# How to store uploaded images in a project folder using JavaScript or OracleJet?

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

From UI using HTML input file, I want to upload images. In JavaScript, I want to store these uploaded images in a specific folder by creating a unique URL to the image. Later, I post the rest of the web-service and I send this image URL to store it along with some other data, and I want to display the images in the UI.

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet.. I couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: Then this question looks pretty broad. SO will help you with specific question but wont provide complete solutions to complex problems.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing, it is not clear whether you are talking about storing the file in browser or on the server. If you want to create a file/folder on your local browser filesystem and store the file in browser (before sending to server or cache a copy) you should read these two articals:

Create a file in browser filesystem:

> https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Create a data URL for image file:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications